# How to take 2nd column in this deliminated table in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, csv, matlab-table

I think the table is tab separated so TSV but my following code never finishes because of the line `ecg = tdfread(filename, '\t');` proposing me that the deliminator `\t` cannot be correct, because the filesize, about 350 MB, should be OK.

```
function ecg = getECG(id, channel, timeStartIndex, timeEndIndex)
 filename = sprintf('/home/masi/Documents/NSRDB/%d.txt', id);
 ecg = tdfread(filename,'\t'); 
 ecg = ecg(timeStartIndex:timeEndIndex, channel);
end
```

### Data Sample 1 example about AD units

```
masi@masiAsus:~/Documents$ head NSRDB/16265.txt 
              0     -33     -65
              1     -31     -65
              2     -39     -61
              3     -41     -61
              4     -37     -59
              5     -31     -53
              6     -27     -47
              7     -19     -37
              8     -15     -27
              9     -13     -19
```

Call for instance `getECG(16265, 1, 1, 4)` for the case at channel 1 (column 1), startTime 1 and endTime 4. 
This can be solved by the following Shai's command, but it fails with 2nd Data sample

```
ecg = dlmread(filename, ' ', 2, 0); % read table with empty columns
```

### Second data set with physical units because AD units failed in data processing

`NSRDB/16265.txt`

```
   Elapsed time    ECG1    ECG2
      (seconds)    (mV)    (mV)
        300.000  -0.005  -0.065
        300.008  -0.015  -0.055
        300.016   0.005  -0.055
        300.023   0.005  -0.075
```

Fig. 1 My current appproach `ecg = dlmread(filename, ' ', 2, 0);` leads to 13 columns

[image]

### Testing Shai's [proposal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40516998/54964) for the second data set

```
% https://stackoverflow.com/a/40516998/54964
ecg = dlmread(filename, ' ', 2, 0); % read table with empty columns
ecg = ecg(:,find(any(ecg,1)));  % keep only non-empty columns
```

Fig. 2 Six columns now where the second data column fails, but also the first empty column is there still

[image]

Data: WFDB MIT-BIH NSRDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [`dlmread`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html) instead of `tdfread`: some of the `'\t'` chars might be spaces...

You can discard the empty columns as a second step

```
ecg = dlmread(filename, ' ', 2, 0); % read table with empty columns
ecg = ecg(:,find(any(ecg,1)));  % keep only non-empty columns
```

Comment: because of the '-' sign present only in some of the numbers you have varying number of spaces. this messes things up.

Comment: I extended the case to their Github https://github.com/ikarosilva/wfdb-app-toolbox/issues/135 - - It is very strange that the data looks like in Fig. 1 after the first read, because there is 300.000 in the first line. - - Why does `dlmread` cannot maintain the significant numbers for all cells?

Comment: @Masi 300==300.000

Comment: The last answer to the case is to change how to read the data initially from WFDB. They have an option ` -c` which allows to read CSV data. - - I think to parse the data here is too challenging.